# CustomNavigationDrawer not working when using curved navigation bar in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, uinavigationbar, navigation-drawer, flutter-animation

Please help with my project when I add
child: getSelectedWidget(index: _selectedPage)
The botom bar works and pages appear without problems, but the sidebar (CustomNavigationDrawer) does not work until it is removed
child: getSelectedWidget(index: _selectedPage)
And don't be when you humiliate it, the bottom bar doesn't work
Please help as soon as possible ❤
[image]

Please help as soon as possible ❤

[image]'

Answer (score 0):

Call your `CustomNavigationDrawer` in the `drawer` property of the `Scaffold` widget. Like this.
[image]